# Вопрос о книге Боба Мартина "Методики гибкой разработки C#"

Tags: c#, ооп, шаблоны-проектирования, agile

Боб в своей книге, в качестве примера, реализует приложение Payroll. Архитектура построена на сценарии транзакций - на каждое действие пользователя есть класс транзакции, работающий с базой данных.
Но вот что не могу понять, например, возьмем кусочек приложения, где для работника "HorlyClassification" добавляют "TimeCard".

```
public class HourlyClassification : PaymentClassification
{
    private double hourlyRate;
    private Hashtable timeCards = new Hashtable();

    public HourlyClassification(double rate)
    {
        this.hourlyRate = rate;
    }

    public double HourlyRate
    {
        get { return hourlyRate; }
    }

    public TimeCard GetTimeCard(DateTime date)
    {
        return timeCards[date] as TimeCard;
    }

    public void AddTimeCard(TimeCard card)
    {
        timeCards[card.Date] = card;
    }
}
```

Тут интересует метод AddTimeCard(Timecard), он ведь вносит очередную карту в коллекцию, которая хранится в памяти, а не в БД.
А транзакция, обещающая добавить TimeCard в БД выглядит так:

```
public override void Execute()
{
    Employee e = database.GetEmployee(empId);

    if (e != null)
    {
        HourlyClassification hc =
            e.Classification as HourlyClassification;

        if (hc != null)
            hc.AddTimeCard(new TimeCard(date, hours));
    }
}
```

Вопрос: Когда же информация о карточке TimeCard заносится в базу данных и как?

Comment: А в чем вопрос то?

Comment: Я пытаюсь понять - то, что карточка сохраняется в память, а не в БД - это недоработка примера кода, или я не понимаю, в какой момент идет сохранение в БД.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Hashtable` - это устаревший класс. Он похож на Dictionary, но есть нюанс - `Hashtable` не бросает исключение, если значения нет, а возвращает null. Поэтому он просто берёт элемент и возвращает его без проверки, был ли он там. А в версии с базой расставлены проверки на null.

Но вообще, ты вопрос не задал...

> Я пытаюсь понять - то, что карточка сохраняется в память, а не в БД - это недоработка примера кода, или я не понимаю, в какой момент идет сохранение в БД.

Так, вопрос я не угадал...

Там где-то дальше есть вариант с базой. Если не ошибаюсь, он явно сказал, что хочет отложить способ сохранения на самый конец разработки, как деталь реализации.

Comment: Отложил способ хранения данных он с помощью интерфейса PayrollDatabase, содержащего "API" для работы с БД - такие методы как "AddEmployee, LoadEmployee ...", и использует в программе класс заменитель InMemoryDatabase : PayrollDatabase, который так же использует Hashtable для хранения. Но транзакции писал вроде как в конечном виде, в приведенном мной коде он дергает метод класса, а не API

Comment: Использует для тестирования? Тесты же не должны менять базу данных.

Comment: Как тогда будет выглядеть этот кусочек кода с добавлением карточки? Т.е. так же нудно добавить карточку в Hashtable в классе HorlyClassification, потому что по содержащимся там карточкам класс высчитывает зарплату, но гдето нужно сохранять карту прямиком в базу.

Comment: У меня сейчас нет книги, я ж по памяти говорю... Вроде, там хранилище в памяти и в базе имеют одинаковый интерфейс и где-то можно перейти с одного на другое.

Comment: Да, вы очень хорошо помните. Но вопрос вот в чем: если я правильно понял, то вся суть такой архитектуры в том, что о базе данных знает один единственный класс - тот, который реализует интерфейс с API "PayrollDatabase". Методы этого интерфейса вызываются только из сущностей "Transaction". Правильно? Так вот,    а карточка, в коде сабжа, добвляется строкой "hc.AddTimeCard(new TimeCard(date, hours));", где hc - часть класса Employee. Теперь возникает вопрос - так как информация о карточке должна отразится сразу в двух местах (1-в БД, 2- в классе Employee, так как он считает зарплату по ним)

Comment: продолжение: то как должна она записываться? В примере кода запись идет в класс Employee, (хотя например все другие сущности пишутся в фейковую БД), значит класс Employee обновившись должен обновить базу? Либо Транзакция кладет карту сама в два разных места. Либо кладет карту в БД, а та обновляет объект Employee

Comment: `public override void Execute()
{
    Employee e = database.GetEmployee(empId);

    if (e != null)
    {
        HourlyClassification hc =
            e.Classification as HourlyClassification;

        if (hc != null)
            hc.AddTimeCard(new TimeCard(date, hours));
        Payroll.UpdateEmployee(e);
    }
}`
Qwertiy - так будет правильно? Если метод UpdateEmployee обновляет всю связанную с Employee информацию в Базе данных

Comment: Когда сохраняется карточка, работник в памяти уже изменён? В любом случае, в базу же только карточку надо сохранить?

Comment: Работник в памяти хранит в себе все связанные с ним карточки. Когда мы вызываем транзакцию - "добавить_новую_карточку(работник, карточка), то программа из базы данных берет работника, он хранит в себе в hashtable свои карточки, программа добавляет в hashtable новую карточку, (теперь мы можем работать правильно с объектом employee в памяти, т.к. карточка в память добавлена. Но мы нигде не записали эти изменения в БД. А значит сразу после того, как в hashtable внесли новую карту - нужно вызывать какой-нибудь метод, типа "UpdateEmployeeCards(empId, employee.hourlyClassification.Cards)"

Comment: А если сначала сохранить карточку в базу, а потом вытащить из неё работника?

Comment: Да, так действительно проще, видимо Роберт Мартин сначала вытаскивает работника, чтобы проверить - тип работника поддерживает добавление карты? нет ли в списке карт работника уже той, что пытаются добавить? . Но и в этом случает, после этих проверок можно добавить карту напрямик в БД, и заново вытянуть работника, да?

Comment: Возможно. Добавить в коллекцию было бы более логично с точки зрения лишних операций. В любом случае, эта логика остаётся ведь в одном месте и при желании всегда можно поменять. Кстати, а метод добавления карточки вообще с работником потом что-то делает? Почему бы не сделать достал - проверил - добавил - ничего не вернул?

Comment: Да, вы правы, спасибо.